# Toggle visibility of polyline using Google API V3

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know you can toggle visibility of markers using google api, but is it possible to toggle the visibility of a polyline using an html checkbox?

Basically, I have a polyline and if the checkbox is checked, I want the polyline visible, and if it is unchecked, I want it hidden. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You toggle the visibility of a polyline the same way you do a marker.

```
setMap(null)
```

To display it again, call the setMap method with a reference to your google.maps.Map object.

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline)

setMap(map:Map) - Renders this shape on the specified map. If map is set to null, the shape will be removed.